# Get google profile information from access token

Tags: php, symfony, google-api-php-client, php-5.5

I have a mobile application that makes use of Google SDK to authenticate the users. That application retrieve an access token from Google and then make a request to my API passing this token. How can I get, in my API, the user's profile using this access token?

I'm trying this:

```
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setClientId('CLIENT_ID');
$client->setClientSecret('CLIENT_SECRET');
$client->setRedirectUri('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob');
// the following token I get through the mobile authentication
$token = array(
    'access_token' => 'ACCESS_TOKEN',
    'refresh_token' => 'REFRESH_TOKEN',
    'token_type' => 'TYPE',
    'expires_in' => 'EXPIRES',
    'id_token' => 'ID_TOKEN',
    'created' => 'CREATED_AT'
);
$client->setAccessToken(json_encode($token));
$plus = new \Google_Service_Plus($client);
$person = $plus->people->get('ID');
```

But I'm getting an error, I think because of the configuration of the client in Google Developers ("installed application") since It's an mobile app.

Comment: Where do you set your scope ?

Comment: I run the application to copy the error and for some reason it worked... Just like that... Thanks anyway